# Read everything that has been echo'd and 'errored' to terminal window?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, sh

I've inherited a complex shell script running on OSX that gets run on a crontab. 
Within the script I would like to periodically read everything in the terminal window and write it to another file... sort of as a log file that I can review later.

Im trying to capture things that have been ECHO'd within the script as well as any error messages displayed on the terminal. (ie /Users/topher/program.sh: line 58: Permission denied)

Is this possible? What command can read from the terminal or output of the program?

Thanks!
topher

Answer (score 0):

If the command you run from cron is as following, all output generated will be written to the `logfile.log` file

```
/Users/topher/program.sh > logfile.log
```

The above command will empty the `logfile.log` file and fill it with output generated by the `program.sh` script. The below command will append the output.

```
/Users/topher/program.sh >> logfile.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tee` to output to both the screen and a file.

```
./some/thing | tee thing.log
```

You might want to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` to dump them both to the log file.

```
    ./some/thing 2>&1 | tee thing.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about OS X's terminal application, but some terminals such as `xterm` can be started with an option that logs everything that appears on the display to a file. Another possibility is to run the `script` program, which captures all characters to and from the terminal to a file.